# cudaMemcpy & blocking

Tags: cuda

I'm confused by some comments I've seen about blocking and cudaMemcpy.  It is my understanding that the Fermi HW can simultaneously execute kernels and do a cudaMemcpy.

I read that Lib func cudaMemcpy() is a blocking function.  Does this mean the func will block further execution until the copy has has fully completed?  OR  Does this mean the copy won't start until the previous kernels have finished?

e.g. Does this code provide the same blocking operation?

```
SomeCudaCall<<<25,34>>>(someData);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

vs

```
SomeCudaCall<<<25,34>>>(someParam);
cudaMemcpy(toHere, fromHere, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Comment: How do I know which calls are blocking, and which are not?  I'm not seeing anything in the library description that say's "I'm a blocking API call".  i.e. There is no mention of blocking in the cudaMemcpy description.  (Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?)

Comment: I suspect any function that involves both the **host** and **device** will will be blocking, unless it includes `async` in its name. All other functions are non-blocking, except for `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your examples are equivalent. If you want asynchronous execution you can use streams or contexts and [cudaMemcpyAsync](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g732efed5ab5cb184c920a21eb36e8ce4.html), so that you can overlap execution with copy.

Comment: Does the cudaMemcpy provide blocking before its copy operation, then after?   i.e. Do I know the kernel has completed before the copy operation starts?    Or is it the blocking at the 'end' of the copy operation that signals the kernel-is-complete AND the copy-is-complete?

Comment: Operations in a single stream don't overlap (they always execute serially). So in a single stream memcpy/asyncMemcpy/kernels will start after all previous operations (kernels or other memcpys) have completed.

Answer (score 6):

According to the NVIDIA Programming guide:

> In order to facilitate concurrent execution between host and device, some function calls are asynchronous: Control is returned to the host thread before the device has completed the requested task. These are:
>
> - Kernel launches;
> - Memory copies between two addresses to the same device memory;
> - Memory copies from host to device of a memory block of 64 KB or less;
> - Memory copies performed by functions that are suffixed with Async;
> - Memory set function calls.

So as long as your transfer size is larger than 64KB your examples are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for this, i couldn't figure out why my calls didn't seem to by synchronous, turned out to be this item: Memory copies from host to device of a memory block of 64 KB or less;